# How to display video from Facebook pages to my IOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

How to display video from Facebook pages to my IOS app. I know about display video from Facebook but I need to display video from Facebook pages
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/videos"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                          id result,
                          NSError *error
                      ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                      }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get video `url` from the Facebook API,
For load the `URL` use `AVPlayer`.

Edit :

Please read this [Facebook developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios)

Comment: How to get video url's

Comment: @ram: Have you check  the result value ?

Comment: Check that your request is ill or not.

Comment: how to set permission and request url?

Comment: I need to display video from Facebook pages